# Cutting marble tile w/ an angle grinder

Tags: tile, marble, grinder, angle

As the title states I'm resorting to cutting my marble tiles with an angle grinder. The grinder and the blade are brand new. I didn't want to spend a lot of money on a wet table saw since all I'm doing is my 9X6 bathroom. I have an 8.5 amp Black & Decker angle grinder, 11,000 rpm, and an appropriate size continuous diamond blade with a max rpm of 15,000 and good with dry/wet use.

I got through about 6in. when let off the power to check the tile out and the blade rattled as it was coming to a stop. The top flange came loose on the angle grinder! I'm afraid to keep going. I've seen people use cut off blades with angle grinders before so I don't really understand what the issue was. Any ideas?

Comment: Pictures might help.

Comment: It sounds like the cutoff wheel is installed backwards.  Admittedly I've done it too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to guess that you may have installed it incorrectly, or failed to figure out what "correctly" is for your particular grinder/blade combination. I cut a lot of tile with a dry diamond blade on a grinder, and I do recall that the setup for the thin diamond blade was different than for a standard thick grinder blade, though I can't recall how it was different without the thing in front of me.